# How to define a dummy/placeholder predicate in GNU Prolog

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I have a Prolog file with the following structure:

```
% LIBRARY SECTION %

foo(X) :- bar(X);
          baz(X).

% USER DATA SECTION %

% e.g. bar(charlie).
```

The user data of the file is intended to be allowed to extended by the user but by default contains nothing. However this causes the query `foo(X).` to fails because `bar/1` and `baz/1` are not defined.

I have tried defining them with placeholder values (i.e. `bar(none).`) but then GNU Prolog complains about discontiguous predicates when user data is added to the bottom of the file.

Is there another way to define a dummy/placeholder version of `bar/1` and `baz/1` so that `foo(X).` does not fail and so that other lines containing `bar` and `baz` can be added to the bottom of the file?

Comment: The `foo` predicate provides answered based on user information (lines of `bar`). Without any user information (no lines of `bar`) typing (`foo(X)`) currently throws an error. I'd like a placeholder so that it can not fail in this case.

Comment: I've updated the question in what is hopefully a more understandable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want to have something along the lines of:

```
ask_bar :-
    % get user input
    assertz(bar(Input)).

foo(X) :-
    bar(X).
```

If this is indeed the problem, you have two options:

First one: Declare `bar/1` as a dynamic predicate:

```
:- dynamic(bar/1).
```

(this is a directive, you just type the `:-` at the beginning of the line.)

Second one: in your program, before any reference to `bar/1`, call the predicate `retractall/1`, like this:

```
main :-
    retractall(bar(_)),
    %....
```

This will delete all `bar`s from the database, *and* it will declare `bar/1` as `dynamic`.

Comment: `dynamic/1` was exactly what I was looking for; thanks!

Comment: @DanielGibbs `retractall` can be useful, too, although even if you do use it it is probably cleaner to have `dynamic` there, it makes your intentions more explicit.